# RSS icon in QuickTabs

Tags: 7, feeds, blocks

I'm using Drupal 7.14 with QuickTabs 7.x-3.4. I have a couple of views with feeds attached to them. I've also set the "Attach To:" field for these feeds. The ones that aren't inside a QuickTab are working fine, but the ones inside QuickTabs won't display their RSS icon. How can I get the views inside QuickTabs to also display their RSS icon?

Answer (score 0):

One way to resolve this is by creating required feeds page with views.

Then add this generated feed pages link manually through Global Text area field of appropriate view in footer using HTML anchor tag. Separate links will be displayed inside each view footer of QuickTabs as per setup.